# JQuery .each of json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, each

Good day!
How can i access the  msg -> items with jQuery .each()?

```
{
            "msg": [
                {
                    "msg_id": "18628",
                    "msg_userid": "12",
                    "msg_username": "Jordan",
                    "msg_type": "msg",
                    "msg_text": "example",
                    "msg_w_to": "0",
                    "msg_created": "03:49:11"
                },
                {
                    "msg_id": "18629",
                    "msg_userid": "12",
                    "msg_username": "Jordan",
                    "msg_type": "msg",
                    "msg_text": "example",
                    "msg_w_to": "0",
                    "msg_created": "03:49:44"
                },
                    {
                    "msg_id": "18936",
                    "msg_userid": "25",
                    "msg_username": "Jack",
                    "msg_type": "msg",
                    "msg_text": "example",
                    "msg_w_to": "0",
                    "msg_created": "23:21:08"
                }
            ],
            "isNew": 0,
            "playSound": 1,
            "lastmsg_from": "Jack",
            "error": "0",
            "append": 0,
            "last_id": "18936",
            "me_username": "Morten"
        }
```

I've searched and tested for hours now but won't work.
Anyone who could help me out?
Thank you in advance!
- M

Comment: What are you trying to loop through? You do not have an array inside of an array.

Comment: How could i access any item in this list with .each()?

Comment: Inside `msg`? Than you need to reference it.

Comment: `$.each($.parseJSON(data).msg, function(i, item) { 
    alert(item.msg_text);
});` Assuming you want to iterate `msg`

Comment: Thank you sir! Exaclty what i was looking for.
Some grumpy old guy flagged this as duplicate question and referred to a plain javascript question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping through the array, you are looping through the object.

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data).msg, function(index, value) {
```